# Time Tracker Tool that can be integrated with azure devops

Tags: time-management, azure

I need a software in which my team can log their time and that can be integrated with Azure Devops. Right now we are using Redmine for this purpose however we cannot integrate it with devops. So please suggest a tool for the same.

Comment: In what way(s) do you need it to integrate with DevOps? Toggl has some integration (but is fairly basic so may not meet your needs).

Comment: Recently I found that [https://www.7pace.com/] **7pace** meets my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company started enforcing the use of 7pace. It has many features for the administrator or team leader to check out, but for us who use it on a daily basis, it is basically a start/stop timer that auto-feeds Completed Work and Remaining Work. It will mess with manually provided times, though. So I would start using from the start of a new sprint only.

Their desktop app still lacks a lot of functionality, so I use it with Toggl to control idle time more accurately. They do not talk to each other, though. I use Toggl to fix 7pace times

Comment: @bippan-kumar, I've just noticed your comment in the question. If it meets your requirements, could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Teamhood has launched an integration with Azure DevOps allowing you to sync data and track time through their interface.
It is also helpful if you want a more visual way to manage your work. As it offers Kanban boards and a Gantt view.

You can learn more here: https://teamhood.com/use-cases/azure-devops-integration/